# XOR of all characters - what does it mean?

Tags: php, xor

I need to send a string to a device via ethernet (socket connection). There is a start bit, a message content, and end-bit and a checksum. The checksum is described as "XOR of all characters".

I do not understand what it means. What does it mean, and how do I generate it with PHP?

Comment: Use a loop that does `$checksum ^= $char` for each character.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: I have not asked for a coded answer. I have asked about a clarification of wording somebody wrote into an official documentation, and for an approach, not for code.

Comment: "XOR of all characters"; php documentation referenced says "TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE, but not both.". I had found that before, but I do not understand how a character can be true or false. Wouldn't any character be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checksum is a code generated based on your input while sending
so that the receiving side can use it to check the data for errors (the receiving side will generate its own checksum and compare it to yours, and raise an error or something when they do not match).

Try this method which returns an XOR checksum:

```php
function GetCheckSum($str)
{
  $r = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $o = ord(substr($str, $i, 1));
    $r = $r ^ $o;
  }
  return $r;
}
```

If it doesn't work for you maybe changing `return $r;` to `return dechex($r);` helps (which converts decimal to hex).